# CefSharp - can't enable webgl

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, cefsharp

I'm initializing my Chromium Browser like this:

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CommandLineArgsDisabled = false;
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Clear();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-3d-apis", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-webgl-draft-extensions", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-gpu", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-webgl", "1");

Cef.Initialize(settings);
var chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
chromeBrowser.Address = "http://get.webgl.org/";       
targetGrid.Children.Add(chromeBrowser);
```

So I try a lot of commands found [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) but to no avail. It does load the website and it says "my browser does support webgl but it isn't enabled." I should see a cube rotating by the way which I don't see. I looked for some SO threads regarding this, one of them complaining about the speed and I copied the initialization from there (only that command line args), still no luck. I also tried turning off the disabling commands before adding these like

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-webgl", "0");
```

without success. Could someone tell me how to initialize CefSharp 55's webgl properly?

Comment: WPF or Winforms control? The WPF one has many issues and I ended up using WinFormsHost to host the control in WPF. Only then I have full touch support and GPU acceleration,

Comment: @Peuczyński WPF control indeed. How did you do with the WinFormsHost?

Comment: Sorry, for the delay. I was afk. I have WinformsHost in MainWindow and I do it like that http://pastebin.com/5PKcXCWh I can upload complete solution if you want

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I tried on my end and yes, I could enable webgl the way you said it :D I'd like you to convert this comment to an answer so I can accept/upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF one has many issues and I ended up using WinFormsHost to host the control in WPF. Only then I have full touch support and GPU acceleration.

Here is how I did it.

```
private CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser wb_Main;

public MainWindow()
{
    var cs = new CefSharp.CefSettings();
    cs.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0";
    CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(cs);

    InitializeComponent();

    CefSharp.Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager().SetStoragePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), true);
    wb_Main = new ChromiumWebBrowser("about:blank");
    wfh_Main.Child = wb_Main;   //WinformsHost control
}
```